# OrientDB performance is very slow, how to increase?

Tags: java, rest, orientdb, graph-databases

We have an application, which uses OrientDB (we are using orientdb-community-2.1.2 version) to get data and display in front-end. We use rest calls to get data from OrientDB. One page has 5 rest calls, each called asynchronously. One rest call corresponds to one OrientDB query.

Each query takes around 25-30 sec to respond and front-end takes around 8 sec to process and display. The whole process makes my application slower. It takes a lot of time to get data from OrientDB and display.

[image]

Please suggest some ways how to improve the performance of OrientDB.